# iPhone crash possibly related to NSUserDefaults

Tags: xcode, cocoa-touch, crash, nsuserdefaults

**New Information:** I have replicated the crash while the phone is connected to my computer with an exception breakpoint enabled, and the application is paused at the moment. If anyone wants to help me with what I should do to get the relevant information before I stop the app, that would be great. It stopped me on a line that was creating a sound which I haven't had a problem with for weeks, so that's confusing.

I recently implemented NSUserDefaults in my game, and it's been causing crashes. The problem is, it never crashes when it'c connected to my computer so I can't actualluy catch the crash - I'm only assuming it has to do with NSUserDefaults.

As of right now I've only stored Ints in my NSUserDefaults. I have realized this morning that I haven't been using the `synchronize` call, could this be causing the crashes?

Also, how do you check for a key that doesn't exist?

The crash occurs when I tap to switch from the game menu into actually playing the game. One of the first lines of code in the game scene's `initWithSize` is a call to check and `NSLog` some default values.

**New information:** After looking at the crash logs it appears that this crash has two parts. First, a KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE which crashes the app when I'm using it, and actually *another* "crash" is being reported a few minutes later, at times which I am sure I am *not* using the app.

**EDIT: CRASH LOG 1:**

```
Hardware Model:      iPhone6,1
Process:             Pixel Pilot [28505]
Path:                /var/mobile/Applications/0DD06667-D5BA-4FAA-A5B1-2747054A79A0/Pixel Pilot.app/Pixel Pilot
Identifier:          com.pixelstewdio.Pixel-Pilot
Version:             1.0 (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2014-11-12 07:34:03.272 -0500
OS Version:          iOS 7.1.2 (11D257)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Subtype: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x000000018516aefa
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   SpriteKit                       0x00000001873ac364 SKCSprite::removeSubsprite(SKCSprite*) + 152
1   SpriteKit                       0x00000001873a0d04 -[SKShapeNode dealloc] + 52
2   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000190a1d470 (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 520
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001843f9b34 _CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 24
4   UIKit                           0x00000001874b6540 _wrapRunLoopWithAutoreleasePoolHandler + 72
5   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001844bb854 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 28
6   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001844b8adc __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 368
7   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001844b8e68 __CFRunLoopRun + 760
8   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001843f9dcc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 448
9   GraphicsServices                0x000000018a0e1c08 GSEventRunModal + 164
10  UIKit                           0x000000018752afc0 UIApplicationMain + 1152
11  Pixel Pilot                     0x000000010009034c main (main.m:16)
12  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000190ff7a9c start + 0

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001910d9aa8 kevent64 + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000190fdd998 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 48

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001910f2e74 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000191171548 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001910f2e74 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000191171548 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001910f2e74 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000191171548 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001910f2e74 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000191171548 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001910d9ca0 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001844bad20 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 180
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001844b8eb0 __CFRunLoopRun + 832
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001843f9dcc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 448
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018444f454 CFRunLoopRun + 108
5   CoreMotion                      0x0000000184bb2538 ___lldb_unnamed_function1441$$CoreMotion + 632
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000191173e18 _pthread_body + 164
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000191173d70 _pthread_start + 136
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000191171550 thread_start + 0

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001910d9ca0 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   AudioToolbox                    0x0000000183d37040 AURemoteIO::IOThread::Run() + 108
2   AudioToolbox                    0x0000000183d3a234 AURemoteIO::IOThread::Entry(void*) + 8
3   AudioToolbox                    0x0000000183c6a278 CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) + 136
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000191173e18 _pthread_body + 164
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000191173d70 _pthread_start + 136
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000191171550 thread_start + 0

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001910d9ca0 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001844bad20 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 180
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001844b8eb0 __CFRunLoopRun + 832
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001843f9dcc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 448
4   AudioToolbox                    0x0000000183c79abc GenericRunLoopThread::Entry(void*) + 156
5   AudioToolbox                    0x0000000183c6a278 CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) + 136
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000191173e18 _pthread_body + 164
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000191173d70 _pthread_start + 136
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000191171550 thread_start + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x000000012cd11870   x1: 0x000000012cd116d0   x2: 0x0000000000000008   x3: 0x000000019112bcdc
    x4: 0x0000000000000000   x5: 0x0000000000000000   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x0000000000000000
    x8: 0x000000018516aee6   x9: 0x00000001915e4ec8  x10: 0x0000000000000067  x11: 0x00000000002c2a00
   x12: 0x0000000000000000  x13: 0x0000000000000000  x14: 0x00000000c1fb8c17  x15: 0x0000000016ed1586
   x16: 0x000000019116d42c  x17: 0x00000001873a0cd0  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x000000012cd11500
   x20: 0x000000012cd11870  x21: 0x0000000193ec4380  x22: 0x0000000193ec4380  x23: 0x00000000a1a1a1a1
   x24: 0x0000000193eb0098  x25: 0x000000010012c048  x26: 0xa3a3a3a3a3a3a3a3  x27: 0x000000016fda6cd0
   x28: 0x0000000000000001  fp: 0x000000016fda6780   lr: 0x00000001873ac344
    sp: 0x000000016fda6760   pc: 0x00000001873ac364 cpsr: 0x60000000
```

**CRASH LOG 2:**

```
Hardware Model:      iPhone6,1
Process:             Pixel Pilot [28606]
Path:                /var/mobile/Applications/0DD06667-D5BA-4FAA-A5B1-2747054A79A0/Pixel Pilot.app/Pixel Pilot
Identifier:          com.pixelstewdio.Pixel-Pilot
Version:             1.0 (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2014-11-12 07:43:50.305 -0500
OS Version:          iOS 7.1.2 (11D257)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000001
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libGPUSupportMercury.dylib      0x0000000189cb46f8 gpus_ReturnNotPermittedKillClient + 12
1   AGXGLDriver                     0x00000001830d3248 SubmitPackets + 196
2   GLEngine                        0x0000000186e3fa78 gliPresentViewES_Exec + 236
3   GLEngine                        0x0000000186e3f908 gliPresentViewES + 192
4   OpenGLES                        0x0000000186e4cc98 -[EAGLContext presentRenderbuffer:] + 76
5   SpriteKit                       0x0000000187389fb8 -[SKView _renderContent] + 1080
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000190fdbfd0 _dispatch_client_callout + 12
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000190fe1c80 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 44
8   SpriteKit                       0x0000000187389b40 -[SKView renderContent] + 96
9   SpriteKit                       0x0000000187387790 __29-[SKView setUpRenderCallback]_block_invoke + 72
10  SpriteKit                       0x00000001873a6a8c -[SKDisplayLink _callbackForNextFrame:] + 284
11  QuartzCore                      0x0000000187100cb8 CA::Display::DisplayLinkItem::dispatch() + 32
12  QuartzCore                      0x0000000187100ac4 CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch_items(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long) + 296
13  IOKit                           0x00000001853fbe70 IODispatchCalloutFromCFMessage + 360
14  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001844aca8c __CFMachPortPerform + 188
15  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001844bb03c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 52
16  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001844baf9c __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 440
17  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001844b91c0 __CFRunLoopRun + 1616
18  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001843f9dcc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 448
19  GraphicsServices                0x000000018a0e1c08 GSEventRunModal + 164
20  UIKit                           0x000000018752afc0 UIApplicationMain + 1152
21  Pixel Pilot                     0x000000010011834c main (main.m:16)
22  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000190ff7a9c start + 0

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001910d9aa8 kevent64 + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000190fdd998 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 48

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001910f2e74 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000191171548 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001910f2e74 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000191171548 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001910d9ca0 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001844bad20 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 180
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001844b8eb0 __CFRunLoopRun + 832
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001843f9dcc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 448
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018444f454 CFRunLoopRun + 108
5   CoreMotion                      0x0000000184bb2538 ___lldb_unnamed_function1441$$CoreMotion + 632
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000191173e18 _pthread_body + 164
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000191173d70 _pthread_start + 136
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000191171550 thread_start + 0

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001910d9ca0 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   AudioToolbox                    0x0000000183d37040 AURemoteIO::IOThread::Run() + 108
2   AudioToolbox                    0x0000000183d3a234 AURemoteIO::IOThread::Entry(void*) + 8
3   AudioToolbox                    0x0000000183c6a278 CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) + 136
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000191173e18 _pthread_body + 164
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000191173d70 _pthread_start + 136
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000191171550 thread_start + 0

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001910d9ca0 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001844bad20 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 180
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001844b8eb0 __CFRunLoopRun + 832
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001843f9dcc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 448
4   AudioToolbox                    0x0000000183c79abc GenericRunLoopThread::Entry(void*) + 156
5   AudioToolbox                    0x0000000183c6a278 CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) + 136
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000191173e18 _pthread_body + 164
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000191173d70 _pthread_start + 136
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000191171550 thread_start + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x00000000e00002e2   x2: 0x000000012cd58950   x3: 0x0000000000000030
    x4: 0x0000000000000333   x5: 0x0000000000000000   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x0000000000000000
    x8: 0x0000000000000001   x9: 0x00000000deadbeef  x10: 0x0000000000003fff  x11: 0x000000012cd5c000
   x12: 0x000000012cd58000  x13: 0x00000000a190c48e  x14: 0x000000008beb8f17  x15: 0x00000000e6b617dd
   x16: 0x000000019116c3fc  x17: 0x0015a535773a04d9  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x000000012f000000
   x20: 0x00000000e00002e2  x21: 0x000000012f00085c  x22: 0x000000010310e043  x23: 0x0000000000000001
   x24: 0x000000000000a050  x25: 0x0000000000000000  x26: 0x0000000000000668  x27: 0x000000000000a6a0
   x28: 0x0000000193eb0098  fp: 0x000000016fd1d890   lr: 0x0000000189cb56ac
    sp: 0x000000016fd1d840   pc: 0x0000000189cb46f8 cpsr: 0x60000000
```

Comment: There will be a crash log generated...

Comment: OK well the crash appears to be unrelated to `NSUserDefaults`, so please correct the title and add the relevant tags.

Comment: I have a hard time believing that it is unrelated, because it started happening immediately after I implemented ` NSUserDefaults ` @trojanfoe

Answer (score 0):

to check if NSUserDefault object is null do this:

```
NSUserDefaults *example = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSObject * object = [example objectForKey:@"test"];

if(object == nil)
{
    //object is nil
}
else
{
   //object isn't nil
}
```

then you need to call the when you do something inside NSUserDefault

```
[example synchronize];
```

Comment: He asked: "As of right now I've only stored Ints in my NSUserDefaults. I have realized this morning that I haven't been using the synchronize call, could this be causing the crashes?

Also, how do you check for a key that doesn't exist?"

Comment: It's very unlikely that not calling `synchronize` will cause a crash and checking that an object exists or not is unlikely to be the cause of the crash.  There are thousands of potential reasons for the crash and nothing will help until the OP decides to show the stacktrace.

Comment: @trojanfoe how can I possibly show a crash log, I have already said that it doesn't crash if it's connected to my computer, only when it isn't.

Comment: @Todd The device will have a crash log that you can obtain, via Xcode, when you plug the device into your Mac.

Comment: @trojanfoe alright I found the crash log. It is very long, what parts should I post?

Comment: @Todd All of it; and ensure it's symbolicated so any references to your source files are displayed.

Comment: @trojanfoe I added the logs. I couldn't add the binary images because I had too many characters.